# Can I convert a buffer + size to TBytes?

Tags: delphi

Given a buffer and its size in bytes, is there a way to convert this to TBytes without copying it?

Example:

```
procedure HandleBuffer(_Buffer: PByte; _BufSize: integer);
var
  Arr: TBytes;
  i: Integer;
begin
  // some clever code here to get contents of the buffer into the Array
  for i := 0 to Length(Arr)-1 do begin
    HandleByte(Arr[i]);
  end;
end;
```

I could of course copy the data:

```
procedure HandleBuffer(_Buffer: PByte; _BufSize: integer);
var
  Arr: TBytes;
  i: Integer;
begin
  // this works but is very inefficient
  SetLength(Arr, _BufSize);
  Move(PByte(_Buffer)^, Arr[0], _BufSize);
  //
  for i := 0 to Length(Arr)-1 do begin
    HandleByte(Arr[i]);
  end;
end;
```

But for a large buffer (about a hundred megabytes) this would mean I have double the memory requirement and also spend a lot of time unnecessarily copying data.

I am aware that I could simply use a PByte to process each byte in the buffer, I'm only interested in a solution to use a TBytes instead.

I think it's not possible, but I have been wrong before.

Answer (score 5):

No, this is not possible (without unreasonable hacks).

The problem is that `TBytes = TArray<Byte> = array of Byte` is [a dynamic array](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Structured_Types_(Delphi)#Dynamic_Arrays) and the heap object for a non-empty dynamic array has [a header](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Internal_Data_Formats_(Delphi)#Dynamic_Array_Types) containing the array's reference count and length.

A function that accepts a `TBytes` parameter, when given a plain pointer to an array of bytes, might (rightfully) attempt to read the (non-existing) header, and then you are in serious trouble.

Also, dynamic arrays are managed types (as indicated by the reference count I mentioned), so you might have problems with that as well.

---

However, in your *particular* example code, you don't actually use the dynamic array nature of the data at all, so you can work directly with the buffer:

```pascal
procedure HandleBuffer(_Buffer: PByte; _BufSize: integer);
var
  i: Integer;
begin
  for i := 0 to _BufSize - 1 do
    HandleByte(_Buffer[i]);
end;
```

Comment: I could also simply increment _Buffer directly rather than using it as an array. Unfortunately that won't detect any index errors (ERangeCheck) which is my main reason to prefer using TBytes. On the other hand I would turn on range checking for debug code only.

Comment: If you are interested in conditional range checking, then wrap the PByte and Size into a record and give it a `property Items[index: Integer]: Byte` with an inline Getter where you can put the range checking.